# Maven cannot reslove dependency

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

We have a maven project that cannot resolve a dependency:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project lima-broker-mule: Could not
>   resolve dependencies for project
>   broker:lima-broker-mule:mule:2.0: The following
>   artifacts could not be resolved:
>   com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj:saaj-impl:jar:1.3-osgi,
>   mx4j:mx4j-jmx:jar:2.1.1-osgi, mx4j:mx4j-impl:jar:2.1.1-osgi,
>   mx4j:mx4j-tools:jar:2.1.1-osgi, mx4j:mx4j-remote:jar:2.1.1-osgi,
>   com.yourkit:yjp-controller-api-redist:jar:9.0.8,
>   org.springmodules:spring-modules-cache:jar:0.9,
>   org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jms_1.1_spec:jar:1.1-osgi,
>   commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.3-osgi,
>   commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1-osgi,
>   dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1-osgi,
>   commons-jxpath:commons-jxpath:jar:1.3-osgi,
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:jar:1.2.2-osgi,
>   xpp3:xpp3_min:jar:1.1.3.4.O-osgi, jaxen:jaxen:jar:1.1.1-osgi,
>   net.java.dev.stax-utils:stax-utils:jar:20080702-osgi,
>   net.sf.saxon:saxon-dom:jar:8.9.0.4-osgi,
>   net.sf.saxon:saxon-xqj:jar:8.9.0.4,
>   net.sf.saxon:saxon:jar:8.9.0.4-osgi,
>   javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1-osgi,
>   org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-j2ee-connector_1.5_spec:jar:1.1-osgi:
>   Could not find artifact
>   com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj:saaj-impl:jar:1.3-osgi in all.repos
>   (http://our.local/artifactory/all)

The problem is that we do not directly reference these dependencies in our pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>

  <!-- Project -->
  <dependency>
      <groupId>de.lineg.lima.broker</groupId>
      <artifactId>lima-broker-service</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
      <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
      <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.4</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
  </dependency>

  <!-- Transports used by the Mule config -->
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
      <artifactId>mule-module-cxf</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
      <artifactId>mule-transport-email</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
      <artifactId>mule-transport-vm</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
      <artifactId>mule-transport-jetty</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.0</version>
      <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
              <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
              <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
          <exclusion>
              <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
              <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
          <exclusion>
              <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
              <artifactId>jasper</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
          <exclusion>
              <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
              <artifactId>jasper-el</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
  </dependency>

  <!-- Unit tests -->
  <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mule.tests</groupId>
      <artifactId>mule-tests-functional</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
      <artifactId>mule-module-client</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
      <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <optional>true</optional>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.easytesting</groupId>
      <artifactId>fest-assert</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
      <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.20061217</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <optional>true</optional>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I don't really know how to resolve this. The dependencies are not in the repositories we have in artifactory and I can't find some of them in any repositories online. I do not know how to find out how theses dependencies are referenced and the dependency plugin from maven can not really help me since the build fails before any output of the dependency plugin can appear.

Any idea how I can solve this issue? Is there any way how I can trace the source of this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could not find artifact
>   com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj:saaj-impl:jar:1.3-osgi in all.repos
>   (http://our.local/artifactory/all)

The `com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj:saaj-impl:jar:1.3-osgi`  artifact is a sun library and some are not available in the public remote repositories(for legality concerns) and besides it is a osgi version (that is not common either).
So it is not so surprising that you don't find it from public Maven repositories.

The `com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj:saaj-impl:jar:1.3-osgi` dependency is not visible in your pom as it is probably a transitive dependency, that is a dependency pulled by a dependency that you include.
As you don't show the whole error message of the build, we cannot say exactly which dependency pulls it.

To solve your problem, you could identify which dependency pulls this missing dependency and look and add if not exist the problem in the issues tracking of the dependency that includes this missing dependency.  Maybe, there is a workaround such as adding a Maven repository that could provide the dependency.

Anyway, you may try to find the library on the web on a reliable source, to download it and install it in your artifactory with the `deploy:deploy-file` goal of the deploy maven plugin.

Look at this for example :
https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-remote.html

Comment: Yes I thought of that solution too. I also agree that osgi versions are very uncommon. Which makes it more interesting to understand where they come from, any idea how to do that?

Comment: It is probably a transitive dependency. I edited to explain

Comment: I figured out including -X shows the sources. I'll be able to solve it from here. Thank you

Comment: The debug flag (`-X`) is indeed very helpful in some cases. You are very welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Most of the artifacts can be found on **mvnrepository.com**

```
<https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj/saaj-impl>
<https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mx4j/mx4j-tools/2.1.1>
<https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj/saaj-impl/1.3.2>
<https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-jxpath/commons-jxpath/1.3>
```

Comment: But not the specific versions that are needed. For example: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj/saaj-impl/1.3-osgi (Taken from error message "Could not find artifact com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj:saaj-impl:jar:1.3-osgi")

Comment: Then i would explictly increase (change) the versions. We hope that nothing cardinal have been changed.

Comment: I would love to do that. But we do not directly use these dependencies as you can see in the pom.xml. I do not know where these dependencies come from.

Comment: Use <dependencyManagement> to set the versions of transitive dependencies.